# How do I fade in/out a background with jQuery, but not its child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu on my webpage that I want to fade out the background of it but not the text. Here is the table for the menu, the jQuery and the CSS.

The Body/Table:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #menu {
            width:900px;
            margin-left:auto;
            margin-right:auto;
            font-family:"britannic bold";
            font-size:200%;
        }

        #allbodies {
            width:900px;
            margin-left:auto;
            margin-right:auto;
        }

        #menu table tr td:hover {
            color:#fff;
        }
    </style>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="menu">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td id="logo" style="width:150px;height:200px;">
                    <a href="template.html" style="text-decoration:none"><img alt="Logo" height="200" src="logo.jpg" width="150"></a>
                </td>
                <td id="home" style="cursor:pointer;width:150px;height:200px;background-color:red;">
                    <p id="menutext" style="text-align: center">HOME</p>
                </td>
                <td id="games" style="cursor:pointer;width:150px;height:200px;background-color:red;">
                    <p id="menutext" style="text-align: center">GAMES</p>
                </td>
                <td id="about" style="cursor:pointer;width:150px;height:200px;background-color:red;">
                    <p id="menutext" style="text-align: center">ABOUT</p>
                </td>
                <td id="contact" style="cursor:pointer;width:150px;height:200px;background-color:red;">
                    <p id="menutext" style="text-align: center">CONTACT</p>
                </td>
                <td id="author" style="cursor:pointer;width:150px;height:200px;background-color:red;">
                    <p id="menutext" style="text-align: center">AUTHOR</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="allbodies">
        <div id="homebody">
            <h1>Home</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="gamesbody">
            <h1>Games</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="aboutbody">
            <h1>About</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="contactbody">
            <h1>Contact</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="authorbody">
            <h1>Author</h1>
        </div>
    </div>jQuery: 
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $("#logo").mouseenter(function(){
                $("#logo").fadeTo("fast",1.0);
            });
            $("#logo").mouseleave(function(){
                $("#logo").fadeTo("fast",0.5);
            });
            $("#home").mouseenter(function(){
                $("#home").fadeTo("fast",1.0);
            });
            $("#home").mouseleave(function(){
                $("#home").fadeTo("fast",0.5);
            });
            $("#games").mouseenter(function(){
                $("#games").fadeTo("fast",1.0);
            });
            $("#games").mouseleave(function(){
                $("#games").fadeTo("fast",0.5);
            });
            $("#about").mouseenter(function(){
                $("#about").fadeTo("fast",1.0);
            });
            $("#about").mouseleave(function(){
                $("#about").fadeTo("fast",0.5);
            });
            $("#contact").mouseenter(function(){
                $("#contact").fadeTo("fast",1.0);
            });
            $("#contact").mouseleave(function(){
                $("#contact").fadeTo("fast",0.5);
            });
            $("#author").mouseenter(function(){
                $("#author").fadeTo("fast",1.0);
            });
            $("#author").mouseleave(function(){
                $("#author").fadeTo("fast",0.5);
            });

            $("#gamesbody").hide();
            $("#aboutbody").hide();
            $("#authorbody").hide();
            $("#contactbody").hide();
            $("#home").hide();
            $("#games").hide();
            $("#about").hide();
            $("#author").hide();
            $("#contact").hide();
            $("#homebody").hide();
            $("#homebody").fadeTo("slow",1.0);
            $("#home").fadeTo("slow",0.5);
            $("#games").fadeTo("slow",0.5);
            $("#about").fadeTo("slow",0.5);
            $("#author").fadeTo("slow",0.5);
            $("#contact").fadeTo("slow",0.5);
            $("#logo").hide();
            $("#logo").fadeTo("slow",0.5);
            $("#menutext").fadeTo("slow",1.0);

            $("#home").click(function(){
                $("#home").fadeIn("slow");
                $("#homebody").fadeIn("slow");
                $("#homebody").show();
                $("#gamesbody").hide();
                $("#aboutbody").hide();
                $("#authorbody").hide();
                $("#contactbody").hide();
            });
            $("#about").click(function(){
                $("#about").fadeIn("slow");
                $("#aboutbody").fadeIn("slow");
                $("#aboutbody").show();
                $("#gamesbody").hide();
                $("#homebody").hide();
                $("#authorbody").hide();
                $("#contactbody").hide();
            });
            $("#contact").click(function(){
                $("#contact").fadeIn("slow");
                $("#contactbody").fadeIn("slow");
                $("#contactbody").show();
                $("#gamesbody").hide();
                $("#aboutbody").hide();
                $("#authorbody").hide();
                $("#homebody").hide();
            });
            $("#author").click(function(){
                $("#author").fadeIn("slow");
                $("#authorbody").fadeIn("slow");
                $("#authorbody").show();
                $("#gamesbody").hide();
                $("#aboutbody").hide();
                $("#homebody").hide();
                $("#contactbody").hide();
            });
            $("#games").click(function(){
                $("#games").fadeIn("slow");
                $("#gamesbody").fadeIn("slow");
                $("#homebody").hide();
                $("#gamesbody").show();
                $("#aboutbody").hide();
                $("#authorbody").hide();
                $("#contactbody").hide();
            });
        }); 
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Indent 4spaces to write code. Now edit your questions code properly.

Comment: Impossible.  A child is part of thee itself.  Make background and text on thy same level, then thy problem shall go.

Comment: Animate the background color instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code (Provided by jQuery ui web site) to find your way:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>jQuery UI Effects - Animate demo</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
        <style>
            .toggler { width: 500px; height: 200px; position: relative; }
            #button { padding: .5em 1em; text-decoration: none; }
            #effect { width: 240px; height: 135px; padding: 0.4em; position: relative; background: #fff; }
            #effect h3 { margin: 0; padding: 0.4em; text-align: center; }
        </style>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                var state = true;
                $( "#button" ).click(function() {
                    if ( state ) {
                        $( "#effect" ).animate({backgroundColor: "#aa0000"}, 1000 );
                    } else {
                        $( "#effect" ).animate({backgroundColor: "#fff"}, 1000 );
                    }
                    state = !state;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="toggler">
            <div id="effect" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
                <h3 class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">Animate</h3>
                <p>Just a line of text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#" id="button" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all">Toggle Effect</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see in this example, you can use `$("#elementid").animate({backgroundColor: "#fff"}, 1000 );` to animate (fade in or out) the background color of your element.

You can find the full example here: http://jqueryui.com/animate/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `fadeTo()` for this because it changes the opacity, and the opacity of a child cannot be different than the opacity of its parent.

You can, however, animate the background color, but you need to include the jquery UI library to do so.

Also, you do not have to choose two different background colors. Instead, you can set an opacity value for the background color.

The code to animate would look like this:

```
$("#parent").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: 'rgba(64, 64, 64, 1)' }, 'fast');
});
$("#parent").mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: 'rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.5)' }, 'fast');
});
```

With the CSS like this:

```
#parent {
    background-color: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.5);
}
```

[**jsfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/87ryF/3/)